# Quotes (inverted commas) creating issue in urdu language

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, urdu

I have a website like ([www.bbcurdu.com](http://www.bbcurdu.com)). Now my problem is, when I adding a new story which having inverted commas or Quotes is not saving in database. If I remove these commas or Quotes then it will save in database. And also fetch and show the result properly.
In phpMyAdmin I'm using **utf8_unicode_ci** (also tried **utf8_general_ci**) in collation column.
Any body please help me to resolve this issue. Thank in advance.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php

include 'config.php';

$uIDStory = $_POST["uIDStory"];
$title = $_POST['titleStory'];
$excerpt = $_POST['excerptStory'];
$story = $_POST['storyStory'];
$catagory = $_POST['catagory'];
$tags = $_POST['tagsStory'];
//$author = $_POST['authorStory'];
$date = $_POST['dateStory'];
$imagecaption =$_POST['imagecaptionStory'];
$imagelinkStory =$_POST['imagelinkStory'];
$imageStory = $_FILES["imageStory"];

$catagory2 = implode(",", $catagory);
/*if(!empty($author)){
$author2 = implode(",", $author);
}*/

$name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $imageStory["name"]);
$uploaded_img_save = "../../../i/story/uploaded/";

if(isset($imageStory) && empty($imagelinkStory)){

if(file_exists($uploaded_img_save.$name)){
    $actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $original_name = $actual_name;
    $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $i = 1;
    while(file_exists($uploaded_img_save .$actual_name.".".$extension)){           
        $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
        $re_name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
        $i++;
        }

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageStory"]["tmp_name"], $uploaded_img_save.$re_name);

$large_img_save = "../../../i/story/825x500/";
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $uploaded_img_save.$re_name );
$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 825, 500 );
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_img_save.$re_name );
imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,825,500,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
$imageContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents( $large_img_save.$re_name, $imageContent );

$large_img_save = "../../../i/story/630x382/";
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $uploaded_img_save.$re_name );
$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 630, 382 );
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_img_save.$re_name );
imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,630,382,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
$imageContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents( $large_img_save.$re_name, $imageContent );

$large_img_save = "../../../i/story/180x109/";
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $uploaded_img_save.$re_name );
$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 180, 109 );
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_img_save.$re_name );
imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,180,109,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
$imageContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents( $large_img_save.$re_name, $imageContent );

    $largelink="http://i.example.net/story/825x500/".$re_name;
    $mediumlink="http://i.example.net/story/630x382/".$re_name;
    $thumblink="http://i.example.net/story/180x109/".$re_name;

    $sql="INSERT INTO story (uIDStory,titleStory,excerptStory,storyStory,catagory,tagsStory,dateStory,imagecaptionStory,thumbStory,topimageStory,imageStory) VALUES ('". $uIDStory ."','". $title ."','". $excerpt ."','". $story ."','". $catagory2 ."','". $tags ."','". $date ."','". $imagecaption ."','". $thumblink ."','". $mediumlink ."','". $largelink ."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    header("location: ../story-edit-publish.php?ID=".$uIDStory);

}else{

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageStory"]["tmp_name"], $uploaded_img_save.$name);

$large_img_save = "../../../i/story/825x500/";
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $uploaded_img_save.$name );
$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 825, 500 );
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_img_save.$name );
imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,825,500,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
$imageContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents( $large_img_save.$name, $imageContent );

$large_img_save = "../../../i/story/630x382/";
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $uploaded_img_save.$name );
$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 630, 382 );
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_img_save.$name );
imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,630,382,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
$imageContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents( $large_img_save.$name, $imageContent );

$large_img_save = "../../../i/story/180x109/";
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $uploaded_img_save.$name );
$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 180, 109 );
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_img_save.$name );
imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,180,109,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
$imageContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents( $large_img_save.$name, $imageContent );

    $largelink="http://i.example.net/story/825x500/".$name;
    $mediumlink="http://i.example.net/story/630x382/".$name;
    $thumblink="http://i.example.net/story/180x109/".$name;

    $sql="INSERT INTO story (uIDStory,titleStory,excerptStory,storyStory,catagory,tagsStory,dateStory,imagecaptionStory,thumbStory,topimageStory,imageStory) VALUES ('". $uIDStory ."','". $title ."','". $excerpt ."','". $story ."','". $catagory2 ."','". $tags ."','". $date ."','". $imagecaption ."','". $thumblink ."','". $mediumlink ."','". $largelink ."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    header("location: ../story-edit-publish.php?ID=".$uIDStory);
};

}elseif (isset($imagelinkStory)) {

    $url = $imagelinkStory;
    $info = new SplFileInfo($url);  
    $file_extension = $info->getExtension(); 
    $img = uniqid().".".$file_extension;
    file_put_contents($uploaded_img_save.$img, file_get_contents($info));

    list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $url );
    $resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 825, 500 );
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $url );
    imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,825,500,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
    $imageContent = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents("../../../i/story/825x500/".$img, $imageContent );

    list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $url );
    $resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 630, 382 );
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $url );
    imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,630,382,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
    $imageContent = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents("../../../i/story/630x382/".$img, $imageContent );

    list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $url );
    $resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 180, 109 );
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $url );
    imagecopyresampled($resampledImage, $source, 0,0,0,0,180,109,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );
    $imageContent = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents("../../../i/story/180x109/".$img, $imageContent );

    $largelink="http://i.example.net/story/825x500/".$img;
    $mediumlink="http://i.example.net/story/630x382/".$img;
    $thumblink="http://i.example.net/story/180x109/".$img;

    $sql="INSERT INTO story (uIDStory,titleStory,excerptStory,storyStory,catagory,tagsStory,dateStory,imagecaptionStory,thumbStory,topimageStory,imageStory) VALUES ('". $uIDStory ."','". $title ."','". $excerpt ."','". $story ."','". $catagory2 ."','". $tags ."','". $date ."','". $imagecaption ."','". $thumblink ."','". $mediumlink ."','". $largelink ."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    header("location: ../story-edit-publish.php?ID=".$uIDStory);

}
```

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal form-bordered form-row-stripped" name="Form1" id="form_sample_3">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php print_r(mt_rand()) ?>"     name="uIDStory" />
        <div class="page-content">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
            <h3 class="page-title">
            Add New Story
            </h3>
            <div class="page-bar">
                <ul class="page-breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                        <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Stories
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Add New Story
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="border-radius:0px !important" onclick="publishStory()"><i class="fa fa-send-o"></i> Publish</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="border-radius:0px !important" onclick="draftStory()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Draft</button>
                    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:0px !important" onclick="previewStory()"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Preview</button>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">


                        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            You have some form errors. Please check below.
                        </div>
                        <?php if (isset($_GET["status"])) {
                            $status = $_GET["status"];
                                if($status == "success"){
                                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                                                <button class='close' data-close='alert'></button>
                                                Story Has been publish successfuly.
                                            </div>  "
                                ;}
                        ;} ?>

                        <div class="portlet-body form">

                        <div class="portlet ">
                            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->


                                <div class="form-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control urdu" name="titleStory"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Excerpt <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <textarea id="maxlength_textarea" class="form-control urdu" maxlength="180" rows="3" name="excerptStory"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <textarea class="summernote" name="storyStory"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Catagory <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <select class="form-control select2_sample1 select3" name="catagory[]" multiple>
                                                <optgroup label="Home">
                                                <option value="HomeTop">Top</option>
                                                <option value="HomeTopSlide1">Slide-1</option>
                                                <option value="HomeTopSlide2">Slide-2</option>
                                                <option value="HomeTopSlide3">Slide-3</option>
                                                <option value="HomeTopSlide4">Slide-4</option>
                                                <option value="HomeLatest1">Latest-1</option>
                                                <option value="HomeLatest2">Latest-2</option>
                                                <option value="HomeLatest3">Latest-3</option>
                                                <option value="HomePakistan1">Pakistan-1</option>
                                                <option value="HomePakistan2">Pakistan-2</option>
                                                <option value="HomeWorld1">World-1</option>
                                                <option value="HomeWorld2">World-2</option>
                                                <option value="HomeSports1">Sports-1</option>
                                                <option value="HomeSports2">Sports-2</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Pakistan">
                                                <option value="PakistanTop">Pakistan-Top</option>
                                                <option value="PakistanList">Pakistan</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="World">
                                                <option value="WorldTop">World-Top</option>
                                                <option value="WorldList">World</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Sports">
                                                <option value="SportsTop">Sports-Top</option>
                                                <option value="SportsList">Sports</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                              
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Tags</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control select2_sample3" name="tagsStory">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Author</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8 component-mt-select"
                                               data-mt-max-tags="9"
                                               data-mt-request-method="POST"
                                               data-mt-request-url="extraphp/search-response.php">
                                                <input type="text" style="width:100% !important;"  class="form-control" data-mt-filter-control/>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class="input-group input-medium date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="+0d">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="<?php echo  date("d-m-Y")?>" name="dateStory">
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Image <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8"> 
                                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                                <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new">
                                                    Select image </span>
                                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">
                                                    Change </span>
                                                    <input type="file" name="imageStory">
                                                    </span>
                                                    <a class="fileinput-new btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#basic">
                                                    Link </a>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">
                                                    Remove </a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="modal fade" id="basic" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                             <div class="form-group" style="border:1px solid #EFEFEF; border-left:0px;">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imagelinkStory" placeholder="http://"/>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.modal -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Image caption <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <textarea id="maxlength_textarea2" class="form-control urdu" maxlength="35" rows="3" name="imagecaptionStory"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="publishStory()"><i class="fa fa-send-o"></i> Publish</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="draftStory()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Draft</button>
                                            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="previewStory()"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Preview</a>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!-- END FORM-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Show some sample data and your code too.

Comment: Tried using implode()/explode?

Comment: There is no usage of implode explode dude.

Comment: @Hassaan I've update my question.

Comment: God knows better what you're trying, that was my wild guess though

Comment: @user3396968 have you tried `utf8_general_ci` in collation column?

Comment: Thanks for you guess Mr.(no name) :P

Comment: @Hassaan yes I've tried this.

Comment: @user3396968 add html too? Oh, look! SQL Injection! Ps. I do have a name :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using utf8_general_ci collation

Comment: you are not escaping your data, try using mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Didn't get you, can you please describe me? This sound looks that it can help me.

Comment: In your $sql variable add
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$uIDStory)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title)."' instead of '". $uIDStory ."','". $title ."'. add mysqli_real_escape_string in all the variables.

Comment: if you read the question, I've said that, when I removed the quotes my data will save in database, normally.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string will not remove your quotes. it will remain as it is. Only it will help you to insert your data along with your quotes.

Comment: ***@AbuHurairaLakdawala***: You should have added your suggestions from the comments to your answer.